# AWS Redshift + Tableau Performance Booster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I'm using AWS Redshift as a back-end to my tableau desktop. AWS cluster is running with two **dc1.large nodes** and database table which I'm analyzing is of 30GB (with redshift compression enabled), I chose Redshift over tableau extract for performance issue but seems like Redshift live connection is much slower than extract. Any suggestions where shall I look into?

Comment: in Live connection, do you do Joins between multiple tables? or does Tableau query only one Redshift table?

Comment: One redshift table (Columns are encoded except sortkeys)

Answer (score 1):

To use Redshift as a backend for a BI platform like Tableau, there are four things you can do to address latency:

1) **Concurrency:** Redshift is not great at running multiple queries at the same time so before you start tuning the database, make sure your query is not waiting in line behind other queries. (If you are the only one on the cluster, this shouldn't be a problem.)

2) **Table size:** Whenever you can, use aggregate tables for better performance. Fewer rows to scan means less IO and faster turnaround!

3) **Query complexity:** Ideally, you want your BI tool to issue simple, fast performing queries. Make sure your source tables are fast, and that Tableau isn't being forced to do a bunch of joins. Also, if your query does need to join multiple tables, make sure any large tables have the same distribution key.

4) **"Indexing":** Technically, Redshift does not support true indexing, but you can get close to the same thing by using "interleaved" sort keys. Traditional compound sort keys won't help, but an interleaved sort key can allow you to quickly access rows from multiple vectors (date and customer_id, for instance) without having to scan the entire table.

**Reality Check**

After all of these things are optimized, you will often find that you still can't be as fast as a Tableau extract. Simply stated, a "fast" Tableau dashboard needs to return data to it's user in <5 seconds. If you have 7 visuals on your dashboard, and each of the underlying queries takes 800 milliseconds to return (which is super fast for a database query), then you still are just barely reaching your target performance. Now, if just one of those queries take 5 seconds or more, your dashboard is going to feel "slow" no matter what you do.

**In Summary**
Redshift can be tuned using the approach above, but it may or may not be worth the effort. The best applications for using a live Redshift query instead of Tableau Extracts are in cases where the data is physically too large to create an extract of, and when you require data at a level of granularity that makes pre-aggregation infeasible. One good strategy is to create your main dashboard using an extract so that exploration/discovery is as fast as possible, and then use direct (live) Redshift queries for your drill-through reports (for instance, when you want to see exactly which customers roll up into your totals).

Answer (score 0):

Few pointers as below

1) Use vacuum & Analyze once your ETL completes
2) Have you created the Table with proper Dist key and Sort Key
3) Aggregation if it's ok from the point of Data Granularity, requirement etc

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove cursor, tableau access data from redshift leader node using cursor. Cursor works iteratively. Thus, impacting the performance.
2. Perform manual analyze on the table, after running heavy load operations. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ANALYZE.html
3.Check the dist key distribution to avoid data skewness and improve performance.